# Colimits in the 2-category of partial functions (which is locally posetal)

Tags: category-theory

I am interested in the category $\mathcal{Pfn}$ of partial functions (using sets as objects), which is well-known to be bicomplete.

And it is also known that one can consider $\mathcal{Pfn}$ as a $2$-category by noticing that every hom-set $Hom(A,B)$ is partially ordered using set-theoretical inclusion. In this sense it holds that $Pfn$ is a locally posetal $2$-category.

I would like to know what it is known about lax colimits in this $2$-category $Pfn$.

- Is it true that every lax diagram has a lax colimit in $Pfn$?
- If so, any reference (or explanation) for a detailed proof on how to build the lax colimit in $Pfn$?

To finish let me ask something related about the so many notions of colimits available for $2$-categories. I wonder whether there is some place where one can find such definitions in a slightly simplified framework:

- Is there some reference explining the different notions of colimits only for the setting of locally posetal $2$-categories?

For example, in Page 37 of [this report](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/sqrl/papers/SQRLreport57.pdf) by Wolfram Kahl it is introduced the notion of lax colimit only in the context of locally posetal categories; but unfortunately, this report does not say anything about all other colimit alternatives (bicolimits, pseudo colimits, etc.)

Comment: Bi(co)limits and pseudo(co)limits in locally posetal categories reduce to ordinary (co)limits (assuming existence). They beocme more interesting in locally preordered categories.

Comment: @Zhen: Why is this true? Given a plain bicomplete category $\mathcal{C}$, there are many ways to look at it as a locally posetal one. Thus, I can imagine it might be the case there is some strange partial order where bicolimits do not exist (while colimits, as a plain category, exist). Is this not possible?

Comment: More precisely: if bi(co)limits or pseudo(co)limits exist, then they are ordinary (co)limits in particular. This is not true for a general bicategory.